# Finding $\alpha, \beta>0$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}-\alpha x-\beta=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $\alpha, \beta>0$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}-\alpha x-\beta=0$.

I wrote $\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7} = 2x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{7}{4x^2}}$ and the last factor has the Taylor expansion $1+\frac{1}{2x}+O(\frac{1}{x^2})$ so that $$\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}-\alpha x-\beta \sim_\infty1+2x-\alpha x-\beta\sim_\infty0\iff\alpha=2,\,\beta=1$$
However, finding that Taylor series was a big hassle. What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply it by $(\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}+(\alpha x+\beta))/(\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}+(\alpha x+\beta))$.

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}-(\alpha x+\beta)&=\frac{\{\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}-(\alpha x+\beta)\}\{\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}+(\alpha x+\beta)\}}{\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}+(\alpha x+\beta)}\\&=\frac{4x^2+4x-7-(\alpha x+\beta)^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}+(\alpha x+\beta)}\\&=\frac{(4-{\alpha}^2)x^2+(4-2\alpha\beta)x+(-7-\beta ^2)}{\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}+(\alpha x+\beta)}\\&=\frac{(4-\alpha ^2)x+4-2\alpha\beta+\{(-7-\beta ^2)/x\}}{\sqrt{4+4(1/x)-(7/x^2)}+\alpha+(\beta/x)}\end{align}$$

Since the denominator approaches a finite value $2+\alpha$, the numerator has to approach a finite value. Hence, $4-\alpha ^2=0\Rightarrow \alpha=2$.

Hence, we have
$$\frac{4-2\cdot 2\beta+\{(-7-\beta ^2)/x\}}{\sqrt{4+4(1/x)-(7/x^2)}+2+(\beta/x)}\rightarrow \frac{4-4\beta}{4}.$$

Comment: Many thanks. But how do we know the limit of $\frac{4x^2+4x-7-(\alpha x+\beta)^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7}+\alpha x+\beta}$ ?

Comment: @rehband: please wait:)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you were still editing. :)

Comment: @rehband: Can you take it from here? I hope this helps:)

Comment: @rehband: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: Fantastic, I think I would've gotten that myself if you had waited 2 more minutes :) Thanks very much!

Comment: @rehband: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a better way but as $x$ tends to $\infty$ we see that the leading order term in the square root is $4x^{2}$. The square root of this is $2x$ so we must require $\alpha=2$. Then notice that:

$$\sqrt{4x^{2}+4x-7}-2x=\frac{4x-7}{\sqrt{4x^{2}+4x-7}+2x}=\frac{4-\frac{7}{x}}{\sqrt{4+\frac{4}{x}-\frac{7}{x^{2}}}+2}\to1$$

so $\beta=1$.

Answer (score 2):

"finding that Taylor series was a big hassle" is not exactly true, if I may.

You properly wrote $$\sqrt{4x^2+4x-7} = 2x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{7}{4x^2}}$$ Now, consider the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+y}$ when $y$ is small. It is given by $$\sqrt{1+y}=1+\frac{y}{2}+O\left(y^2\right)$$ Now, replace $y$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ since $\frac{7}{4x^2}$ is much smaller and you are done.

Comment: Always a good answer. (+1)

Comment: And the reason we can omit $\frac{7}{4x^2}$ is that it's small compared to $\frac{1}{x}$? Could we write $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{7}{4x^2}} \sim_\infty \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} \sim_\infty \frac{1}{2x}$ ?